# How to get hashlib to work on both Python2 and Python3

Tags: python, python-3.x, hashlib

This code works fine when using Python2, however when using Python3 it gives me this error:

> Checksum error: bob.tgz, Unicode-objects must be encoded before
> hashing

I then made some changes to use byte like objects in the sha256 object but then I started getting:

> Checksum error: bob.tgz, 'utf-8' codec can't decode byte 0x8b in
> position 1: invalid start byte

So my question is how do I get this code to work on both Python2 and Python3?

```
import hashlib

filepath = "bob.tgz"
filepath_hashed = "bob.tgz.hashed"
thekey = "asdf1234"
try:
    m = hashlib.sha256()

    file_contents = None
    with open(filepath, "r") as f_in:
        file_contents = f_in.read()
        m.update(file_contents)
    m.update(thekey)
    with open(filepath_hashed, "w") as f_out:
        f_out.write(file_contents)
        f_out.write("~~CHECKSUM~~%s" % m.hexdigest())
except Exception as e:
    print("Checksum error: %s, %s" % (filepath, e))
```

Comment: Try to add `b` to the file modes and prefix the `"~~CHECKSUM..."` with `b` (should be supported since Python 2.6).

Comment: Added, works on 2, but on 3: Checksum error: bob.tgz, Unicode-objects must be encoded before hashing

Comment: Prefix the key's `"asdf1234"` with `b` as well.

Comment: Added, works on 2 but on 3: Checksum error: bob.tgz, %b requires a bytes-like object, or an object that implements __bytes__, not 'str'

Comment: Actually you should not simply catch all exceptions and print the error message. You loose important information without the traceback. But in this case here it is clear that the `hexdigest` method returns a Unicode object. You should create a function which converts Unicode to byte strings if on Python 3 and doing nothing otherwise. This can be done e. g. by a line `bytes` which will throw an exception on Python 2 because it isn't defined there.

Comment: wow adding m.hexdigest().encode('utf-8') worked after the other additions. thanks.